# Another word/phrase for "In addition to"

Tags: phrase-requests

What is an alternative phrase or word for "in addition to"?

Here's an example sentence:

> In addition to the tasks listed above, we ask that you complete the following tasks as time permits.

Is there a word or phrase that can replace "in addition to" in the above sentence without altering anything else in the sentence?

Comment: "Further to the tasks..." would also work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two expressions that do not alter the rest of the sentence are the following:

**Besides** the tasks listed above, ...
**As well as** the tasks listed above...

[Linking words](http://www.english-at-home.com/grammar/linking-words/)