# Short Word or Abbreviation for "In Addition to"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Similar, but not a duplicate of [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/159288):

My resume has a table (two columns), with multiple categories of skills within each column.

```
Related Skill Set #1  | Related Skill Set #3
- skill               | - skill
- skill               | - skill
- skill               |
                      | Related Skill Set #4
Related Skill Set #2  | - skill
- skill               |
- skill               | Related Skill Set #5
- skill               | - skill
                      | - skill
*Unrelated Skill Set* | - skill
- skill               | - skill
- skill               |
- skill               |
```

Most skills are directly related to the job for which I applying. However, I need a heading that intrinsically describes skills that are an added bonus, or still valuable, but not directly required.

For example (I am not a teacher), some skill sets would be: working with children, communication skills, the subject that is taught under the position, and so on. Additional skills that aren't directly required (for this example) but might be helpful (or good to note) are: CPR training, special needs experience, and so on.

I am looking for a short word, phrase, or abbreviation that defines a new category in the table that will contain extra skills. It seems there's a Latin phrase for anything and everything; certainly there is for this?

Comment: I would use 'required' for the required skills and 'related' for the related skills.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you, but the format I have currently is a little different. I have a broad set of skills that would apply to the role (which is technical). They fit under multiple categories, and don't exactly match any role specifically. This is why I chose to break them up into categories, and just add a category for miscellaneous. I'm afraid breaking it down into two categories would make it hard to read.

Comment: Sorry, I understood that your table has two columns. The skills in the left column are required by the job description, the skills on the right are related to the job. What is wrong with the two criteria you already stated in the question: 'required' and 'related'?

Comment: @WeatherVane Going purely off of the position I would like to apply for, if I had one column for required and the other for related, they would be mixed: I can add something that is required, then add three related skills to that requirement. What happens is a short left column, then a long and mixed up right column. If I group by category, I have the job requirements intermixed in a digestible format. And even better, I can reuse the table for other similar positions.

Comment: @Pheric In this question I would get rid of the table, which is merely confusing the issue as it's not a good way of laying out a resumé. And your "I am not a teacher" should probably be "if I were a teacher". I still think you're going to end up with *Required skills* and *Related skills* though, and the "related" group needs to come at the end.

Comment: “Other” contrasts with “Related.”

Comment: "required skills" and "desired skills"?

Comment: The word *plus* suggests itself.  You have all the requisite skills and experience, *plus* all these bonus skills and experience to attract your potential employer.